# When searching for a text in a file i'm getting the same result multiple times why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method i'm using to search for the text in files.

```
int tfiles = 0;
        int tdirs = 0;
        void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root, string filesExtension, string textToSearch)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
            string[] workerResult = new string[4];
            try
            {
                files = root.GetFiles(filesExtension);
                tdirs ++;
                workerResult[1] = root.FullName;
                workerResult[3] = tdirs.ToString();
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0,workerResult);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {

            }

            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {

            }

            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
                {
                    tfiles += files.Length;
                    if (files.Length > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;

                            if (Vara == 1)
                            {
                                workerResult[2] = files[0].FullName;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    workerResult[0] = tfiles.ToString();
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, workerResult);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

                foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
                {
                    WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo,filesExtension,textToSearch);
                }
            }
        }
```

The part that i search in the files:

```
if (files != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
                    {
                        tfiles += files.Length;
                        if (files.Length > 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;

                                if (Vara == 1)
                                {
                                    workerResult[2] = files[0].FullName;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

And in the progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] results = (string[])e.UserState;
            pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt.Invalidate();
            label3.Text = results[0];
            label2.Text = results[1];
            label4.Text = results[3];
            label3.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            if (results[2] != null)
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(results[2]);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that i see each result in the ListViewCostumControl.lvnf multiple times instead only one time.

Sometimes i see results 5 times in a row or 7 times or 3 times but i want it to add to the listView each result only once.

UPDATE

I used a break point trying to find the problem.
I found that sometimes the listView is adding the same result(results[2]) twice same directory same file for example Form1 with the same directory.

Here is a screenshot when it's adding the Form1.cs twice.

[image: Form1 twice]

You can see same directory and Form1 twice.

Ok now i checked the Form1 file in this directory and i see that the text Form1 appears 4 times. So maybe that's making the problem ? But it's showing me Form1.cs as result sometimes once sometimes twice if the text Form1 appears 4 times in Form1.cs why it's not adding as results the same Form1.cs 4 times to listView ?

So another thing i need to find how to do is that if in a cs file there is the text Form1 more then once report it to listView only on the first time where it seen in Form1.cs

For example lets say in the directory and file Form1: D:\C-Sharp\1\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\Form1.cs

In this Form1.cs the text Form1 is there 4 times. in Line 3 line 6 line 44 line 88 then i want to report result[2] only once with the Line 3 of Form1.

So in listView i will see only once: D:\C-Sharp\1\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\Form1.cs

Sometimes i see in listView twice as result:

D:\C-Sharp\1\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\Form1.cs

But sometimes i see in listView only once the:

D:\C-Sharp\1\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\ImagesPixelsColorsComparison\Form1.cs

Can't figure out why as results Form1.cs show twice added twice to listView.
Why not 4 times ? Why not only once ?

I also changed in the WalkDirectoryTree the for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    tfiles += files.Length;
                    if (files.Length > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (File.ReadAllText(files[i].FullName).Contains(textToSearch))
                            {
                                workerResult[2] = files[i].FullName;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {
                            string nonono = "";
                        }
                    }
                    workerResult[0] = tfiles.ToString();
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, workerResult);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
```

But it didn't change much same problem as it was vefore with the foreach and the Vara variable.

I also changed this line from files[0] to files[i]

```
workerResult[2] = files[i].FullName;
```

But the problem still exist as before Form1.cs is added twice to the listView.

Comment: `if(!lvnf.Item.Contains(result[2]) => Add ?!`

Comment: First this line give me error: if(!ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Contains(results[2])) Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Contains(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem)' has some invalid arguments and Error 6 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

Comment: Second what cause in the WalkDirectoryTree method to give same multiple results ? I can't figure out.

Comment: okay ... weired. To debug i would recommend to just dump all the hits to 1 list when ever `File.ReadAllText(files[i].FullName).Contains(textToSearch)` is  `true` save it to a list. Does this list contains dublicats when you debug ?

Comment: Ok i did the test i make one instance for the List in the top of form1 and inside the recursive method WalkDirectoryTree i'm adding the items to the List when it's true and it's adding the items only once each time !!! So with the List it's working fine but for some reason with the reporting the results to the listView it's showing it twice. So something is wrong i guess with the way i report progress the results or the way i'm building the results array.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple:

```
WalkDirectoryTree("C:\temp", "*.txt", "test") //Lets say you start like this
```

`files = root.GetFiles(filesExtension)` Here is the problem

What you need here is `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` because later when you use

```
subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
{
   WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo,filesExtension,textToSearch);
}
```

You search for files you already got...

Here an example:

When calling `WalkDirectoryTree("C:\temp", "*.txt", "test")`
and we assume you got 3 folders under `C:\temp`:

the first call gives you all files in `C:\temp, C:\temp\01, C:\temp\02, C:\temp\03`

then, you call `foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)` here you get your duplicates.

**OR**

> You use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` and delete the part where you
>   enumerate the SubDirs.

**SideNote:**

```
int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
if (Vara == 1)
{
   workerResult[2] = files[0].FullName;
}
```

This is not a very good way to check if the file contains the text do it like this:

```
if (File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Contains(textToSearch))
{
   workerResult[2] = files[0].FullName;
}
```

You really dont need the int here. The `Contains()` will return a boolean true if string is contained, false if not.

Comment: I added now to the GetFiles line SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly but got same results. I did: files = root.GetFiles(filesExtension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

Comment: Maybe the problem is something with the loop i'm doing over the files ? With the Vara variable ?

Comment: @מנימנחם have you checked your drive ? You sure the files are there only once ?

Comment: I will update my question with a screenshot of it to make it easy to understand.

Comment: No they are only once. I also used a break point now and it's strange sometimes it's adding to the listView same item same result twice but not all the time the same twice.